# libfreenect cmake error in wrapper cpp file

Tags: linux, cmake, kinect, libfreenect2

im trying to install kinect 360 in my ubuntu 16.04 system and in the libfreenect library im in front of a cmake problem. What should i do to solve this?. Thank you very much guys!

```
In file included from /home/evdo/Kinect/libfreenect/wrappers/cpp/cppview.cpp:27:0:
/home/evdo/Kinect/libfreenect/wrappers/cpp/libfreenect.hpp:182:8: error: ‘unique_ptr’ in namespace ‘std’ does not name a template type
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> m_rgb_buffer;
    ^
/home/evdo/Kinect/libfreenect/wrappers/cpp/libfreenect.hpp: In member function ‘void Freenect::FreenectDevice::setVideoFormat(freenect_video_format, freenect_resolution)’:
/home/evdo/Kinect/libfreenect/wrappers/cpp/libfreenect.hpp:115:5: error: ‘m_rgb_buffer’ was not declared in this scope
 m_rgb_buffer.reset(new uint8_t[mode.bytes]);
 ^
wrappers/cpp/CMakeFiles/freenect-cppview.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'wrappers/cpp/CMakeFiles/freenect-cppview.dir/cppview.cpp.o' failed make[2]: *** [wrappers/cpp/CMakeFiles/freenect-cppview.dir/cppview.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:810: recipe for target 'wrappers/cpp/CMakeFiles/freenect-cppview.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [wrappers/cpp/CMakeFiles/freenect-cppview.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Search for the error and you will get many hits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a line of code to CmakeLists.txt as shown below.

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS}  -std=c++11")
```